# slicing a dataframe by text within a text

Tags: python, pandas, slice, data-analysis

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

saf_data = {'col1': ['U1', 'U2', 'U3', 'U4'], 'col2': ['1', '2|6', '4a|6a', '6b']}

saf_df = pd.DataFrame(saf_data)
```

I want to do the following

1. keep all elements in `col1` that contain the "text" `6` in `col2`

So the expected outcome should contain `['U2', 'U3', 'U4']` or be a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 col1   col2
0   U2    2|6
1   U3  4a|6a
2   U4     6b
```

Can someone help me how I can do that? Please **I am looking for the most efficient and general code, because my dataframe is quite large.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC `str.contains`

```
saf_df[saf_df.col2.str.contains('6')]
Out[51]: 
  col1   col2
1   U2    2|6
2   U3  4a|6a
3   U4     6b
```

Since you mentioned your `df` is quit large, I will recommend using `for loop` here, see the timing below

```
%timeit saf_df[saf_df.col2.str.contains('6')]
10 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop
%timeit saf_df[['6' in x for x in saf_df.col2]]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.14 ms per loop
```